# Bind XML response to HTML in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, xml2js

I have a requirement that my API will return XML response. I want to display it on HTML page using **Angular2**. How do I achieve that?
I am using xml2js node module to parse xml.
this is my code

```
 import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
  /* This is sample demo I am working on.In future data will come 
      from API
  */
  showData() {
     const xml = '<root>Hello xml2js!</root>';
      xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
      console.dir(result);
    });
  }
```

From the above code I want to display "Hello xml2js" in HTML page.
How do I achieve that in angular 2?

In console I get following result:
[image]
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';

  text = "";
/* This is sample demo I am working on.In future data will come 
      from API
  */
  showData() {
     const xml = '<root>Hello xml2js!</root>';
      xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
      this.text = result;
    });
  }
```

In html

```
<p>{{text}}</p>
```

Comment: Tried  with above but getting an error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined"

Comment: declare text in the component. text = "";